# Submit form concat two urls when i click on submit button in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am new in laravel and the problem is i create two function one for view the edit form and the other function for update the data but when i click on submit it concat view and update both url but in form action i had only gave it the update url.

Here is my web.php code

```
Route::post('addStudent',[StudentController::class,'addStudent'])->name('addStudent');
Route::get('/president',[PresidentController::class,'index']);
Route::get('editPresident/{id}',[PresidentController::class,'presidentEditForm']);
Route::post('updatePresident',[PresidentController::class,'updatePresident'])->name('updatePresident');
```

And this is my controller code

```
// view president edit from
    function presidentEditForm($id)
    {
        $userData=$this->user->getPresidentById($id);
        return view('president/edit_president',['president'=>$userData]);
    }
    // update president from the admin
    function updatePresident(Request $data)
    {
        $validated = $data->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'mob_no'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'join_date'=>'required'
        ]);
        // saving inputs into variables
        $firstname=$data->first_name;
        $lastname=$data->last_name;
        $email=$data->email;
        $mob_no=$data->mob_no;
        $city=$data->city;
        $password=$data->password;
        $joiningdate=$data->join_date;
        $joiningtill=$data->join_till;
        $userid=$data->userId;
        // saving into the users object
        $this->user->firstname=$firstname;
        $this->user->lastname=$lastname;
        $this->user->email=$email;
        if($password!="")
        {
            $this->user->password=$password;
        }
        $this->user->joining_from=$joiningdate;
        $this->user->joining_till=$joiningtill;
        $this->user->city=$city;
        $this->user->mobile_no=$mob_no;

    }
```

And this is my view code

```
@extends('includes.header')
@section('content')
<x-pagetitle data="Edit President"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <button type="button" onclick="back()" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs btn_back my-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Go Back</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="updatePresident" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @foreach ($president as $p)
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                            <label for="first_name">First name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First name" name="first_name" value="{{$p['firstname']}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{$p['usr_id']}}">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('first_name')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                            <label for="last_name">Last name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" name="last_name" value="{{$p['lastname']}}">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('last_name')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="email">Email*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{$p['email']}}">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('email')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="password">Password*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('password')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="mob_no">Phone No/Mobile No*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob_no" placeholder="Mobile/Phone No" name="mob_no" value="{{$p['mobile_no']}}">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('mob_no')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="city">City*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" name="city" value="{{$p['city']}}">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('city')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="join_date">Joining Date*</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="join_date" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#join_date" name="join_date" value="{{$p['joining_from']}}" placeholder="Job Start Date">
                                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#join_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('join_date')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-2">
                            <label for="join_till">Joining Till</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="join_till" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#join_till" name="join_till" value="{{$p['joining_till']}}" placeholder="Job Start Date">
                                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#join_till" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                @error('join_till')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTSPa.png)

Comment: You need to add @method('patch') in your form for update action and your action becomes action="{{ route('updatePresident') }}"

Comment: action="{{ route('updatePresident') }}" this giving me error "Route [updatePresident] not defined" when i added it into form

Answer (score 0):

you need to add @method('PUT') in your form then you can update your data
you should check the route through

php artisan route:list

and check there route method and you can use other method like this

@method('your method name ')

Comment: It is adding my view form url then action url why i dont knw

Answer (score 0):

First add `@method('put')` into your form.

And, send object id into the route then change the update function into simple after validate

```
$user->update($request->all());
```